# How to use data-i18n attributes from older project

Tags: javascript, i18next

I am hoping to upgrade an old project's i18next implementation. The i18n-related code is v1.11, which predates even the breaking changes mentioned for v2.x+

Once upon a time when jQuery was the norm, i18next.js would search the document for translations provided with `data-i18n="key"` attributes, and fill them in. If you changed languages, you simply called `$(parent).i18n()` and it would scan the document and fill them in.

I just read the most recent documentation, and they seem to be sticking strictly to the one-key-at-a-time paradigm. No data-attributes, just `i18next.t('key')`.

Have I missed something, or do I need to write my own iterator to go through the document and make the updates? Their code samples seem to indicate "yes", but I have a hard time imagining that anybody sane would want to go through their document and update entries by selector, one-by-one.

To be clear: I'm not asking for a full migration guide. I have headaches ahead of me, this much I know. But I'm hoping I've missed something about using data-i18n attributes, which no longer appear to have built-in support.

Comment: are you using any framework or is is it just jQuery and Javascipt?

Comment: Hey Dipen, the original version had jQuery as a dependency. My preference with the updated version is to NOT use jQuery. We are not using a framework. So just plain ol' JavaScript.

Comment: in that case you can still se the same logic as it is used for jQuery plugin, instead of jQuery replace specific code with plain javascript: https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: I'm not sure which part of that link has the analogy I'm looking for, but I'll look more carefully. ;-) Once we're sure it's the right answer, you should put your answer formally!

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying now that I'm more awake-- repurpose the design intention of the jQuery plugin even without jQuery: grab the elements however, parse the data attributes, and supply the translation, swapping in plain JS instead of jQuery. Not a bad idea! Wasn't the silver bullet I was hoping for, but it's better than completely reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Yup exactly, all you need is already there you just need to convert jQuery calls to javascript and it should work as it was earlier!

Comment: About the iterator, selector and one-by-one that's basically how a jquery function works. What about something as simple as Array.from(document.all).filter(someFilter).forEach(applyFunction)?

Comment: @netizen should do the trick, too. I shelved the project for a minute (other stuff came up) so I haven't gone into the jQuery plugin to see what other "gotchas" it is covering. But what you say makes sense. Both answer the question, really: "is there something built-in that I'm missing?" and the answer isn't necessarily "no" outright, but rather, "you could just write your own." Which is true enough. :)

Comment: There's a new more complete guide here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3